# Force Spring 3.1 to use Jackson 2 when Jackson 1 JARs on the classpath

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I have a Spring MVC 3.1 app built with Maven and I want to use Jackson 2 for JSON serialization/deserialization.  I am including Jackson 2.x dependencies explicitly in my pom.xml file, although my app has a different dependency that uses Jackson 1.9.9 internally, and I can't easily remove that dependency.

Because of both Jackson libs being present on the classpath, it seems like Spring is defaulting to using Jackson version 1.9.9.

How do I force Spring MVC to use Jackson 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make this work, I had to adjust my mvc:annotation-driven xml configuration element to work as follows:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
  <mvc:message-converters register-defaults="false">
    <bean id="jacksonMessageConverter" 
      class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"/>
  </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

Answer (score 1):

Support for Jackson 2 was added in [Spring 3.2](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-9302) and back-ported to [Spring 3.1.2](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-9507). Once you have one of those versions you just need the jackson-databind library on the classpath as [described here](http://norrisshelton.wordpress.com/2012/07/15/spring-3-mvc-with-json-via-jackson-2-0/)

Alternatively, Keith Donald included the source for MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/2423129) as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10421183/252840).

Comment: I have both Jackson 1.9.9. and 2.1.2 libs on my classpath, and couldn't easily remove v1 of Jackson since it's used by a library that I need.  Spring 3.1 seems to preference Jackson 1 over 2 when both are present, so I had to explicitly tell Spring to use v2 of Jackson as per my answer.