# ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter

Tags: java, spring, maven, resttemplate

I am completely a beginner at Spring (you can see that in my code :) ). I just wanted to test the class RestTemplate but I got a `ClassNotFoundException`.
So the code is:

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
public class RestClient {
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;
    public String getJiraIssueAsJson(){
        Object o = restTemplate.getForObject(..., Object.class);
        System.out.println("..."+o.getClass());
        return null;
    }
    public void setRestTemplate(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("rest-client-context.xml");
        RestClient restClient = context.getBean("restClient", RestClient.class);
        restClient.getJiraIssueAsJson();
    }
}
```

context.xml

```
<beans ...>
    <bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverte‌​‌​r"/>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="restClient" class="org.googlecode.happymarvin.jiraexplorer.RestClient">
        <property name="restTemplate" ref="restTemplate"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

pom.xml

```
<project ...>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.happymarvin</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>jiraminer</artifactId>
    <name>Happy Marvin JIRA Miner</name>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <jackson-version>1.9.13</jackson-version>
    </properties>
</project>
```

parent pom.xml

```
<project ...>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.happymarvin</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>Happy Marvin parent project</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <org.springframework.version>4.0.0.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Exception

```
Jan 07, 2014 10:18:24 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@730eb2f0: startup date [Tue Jan 07 10:18:24 GMT 2014]; root of context hierarchy
Jan 07, 2014 10:18:24 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [rest-client-context.xml]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'restTemplate' defined in class path resource [rest-client-context.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverte‌​‌​r#77624896' of type [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverte‌​‌​r] while setting bean property 'messageConverters' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverte‌​‌​r] for bean with name 'org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverte‌​‌​r#77624896' defined in class path resource [rest-client-context.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverte‌​‌​r
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverte‌​‌​r
```

I have this exception when I try to run the main method from eclipse.
I can think of something like the spring jars cannot be seen but I don't know why...
Can you please help me?

Comment: Do you have the Sprin-web jar in your classpath ?

Comment: Hi SiN, thanks for help! The spring-web is in the maven dependencies. I thought the maven dependencies are on the classpath in eclipse. or am I mistaken?

Comment: spring 4.0.0 ? I can see that class should in spring-web.jar as of 3.0.x may be its not there in 4.0 ?

Comment: I found the class MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverte‌ in eclipse in the maven dependencies (spring-web-4.0.0.jar). However I tried the spring 3.0.5 too but the result was the same... :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

i tried to copy paste your spring beans to a project but something strange is wrong with

`<bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverte‌​‌​r"/>`

this line, specifically there seems to be some invisible characters before the last `r` in `Converter` try typing that classname again manually.

if this is the case then its the craziest thing i have seen for sometime :D

Also `MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter` is deprecated in 4.0.0 there is something newer. And you will need to add dependencies for jackson as well to get things working. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10420040/jackson-2-0-with-spring-3-1/13435703#13435703) should be helpful.

Comment: that would explain the title of this post (the gap before the r) too. the .class file is in spring-web. It may be damaged in the local repo?

Comment: ya i thought it was a typo there. i think OP copied from some websource which had those characters there. i copied this into eclipse and i wouldnt notice anything different. i kept staring at the classname for like whole 5 mins :D

Comment: now i notice that in the stacktrace `r` is colored differently too

Comment: Oh my God! ... I really don't know how I did this... :)   
You are right, there was ... something before the letter 'r' but I don't know what. Anyway sorry about the confusion and thank you for the help! Now it is working.

Comment: it can be a nightmare debugging things like this. i was like whats the different between `MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverte‌​‌​r` and `MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter` :D

Answer (score 30):

The first major version of Jackson is no longer supported in Spring 4.  The class you want to use is now 
`org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`.  Make sure that you have com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.x.x on your classpath.

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem. Just for the information we need to add 3 jars in classpath becasue of its dependency on each other: 1. jackson-core-x.x.x.jar, 2. jackson-databind-x.x.x.jar, 3. jackson-annotations-x.x.x.jar

Answer (score 10):

I faced same issue. Fixed using `org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` instead of `org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverte‌r`

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the following to your pom.xml (not parent pom.xml)

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: This is a possible option when spring autoconfigure was in the project as well.
But looks like it is not related to the original question.

Answer (score 2):

I had the issue, got it fixed by adding following dependencies in pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10420040/jackson-2-0-with-spring-3-1/13435703#13435703)!

Comment: **Anyone is pulling hairs because of this** - key is that you should use jackson version 2.6.3+, especially when you are using Spring version 4.2.6+ .. I tried with many versions of jackson library and still had this issue, but as soon as I used version 2.6.3 this issue got resolved, so this means that earlier versions of jackson library references `org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter` but since in hire versions of Spring this is replaced by `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`, so there will be `ClassNotFoundException:MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter`

Comment: i dont know what this answer fixes, but it is surely not this question.

Answer (score 0):

Programmaticaly you can do your configuration like this:

```
public class AppConfiguration {

   ...
    @Bean
    public HttpMessageConverters customConverters() {
        HttpMessageConverter<?> jacksonMessageConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
//        HttpMessageConverter<?> another = ...
        return new HttpMessageConverters(jacksonMessageConverter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.3</version>
</dependency>
```

it's worked for me

Comment: <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies> also need