# Ajax and Java web service strange error

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jax-rs, jax-ws

I got a really weird error. I successfully run my code and consume the web service. The service return 200 code. But jquery ajax executes error function instead of success. I post the information (Nothing on console):

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(
    function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'Test/Service/hello',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: {name: 'testing'},
            error: function () {
                $('#text').html('<p>An error has occurred</p>');
            },
            success: function (data) {

                $("#text").html(data.d);
            },
            type: 'POST'
        });
    });
```

Java:

```
package com.morethansimplycode.webservice;

import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/Service")
public class Service {

    public Service() {
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/hello")
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String hello(@WebParam(name = "name") String txt) {

        return "Hello " + txt + " !";
    }
}
```

Chrome info:

```
Remote Address:[::1]:8080
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/WebService/Test/Service/hello
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Response Headers
view source
Content-Length:17
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Tue, 01 Dec 2015 21:24:26 GMT
Server:GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1
X-Powered-By:Servlet/3.1 JSP/2.3 (GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1  Java/Oracle Corporation/1.8)
Request Headers
view source
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:es-ES,es;q=0.8,ca;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,pt;q=0.2,ru;q=0.2
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:9
Content-Type:application/json
Host:localhost:8080
Origin:http://localhost:8080
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://localhost:8080/WebService/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Request Payload
name=paco
```

Preview:

```
Hello name=testing !
```

What's happening?

Edit 1:

Works with this call:

```
$(document).ready(
        function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'Test/Service/hello',
                dataType: 'text',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: {name: 'paco'},
                error: function () {
                    $('#etiqueta').html('An error has occurred');
                },
                success: function (data) {

                    console.debug(data);
                    $("#etiqueta").html('<p>' + data + '</p>');
                },
                type: 'POST'
            });
        }
);
```

But i don't know how can i send an object from the Web Service to the JS as Json to use it with data.d, etc...

Edit 2:

Working correctly as follows:

JS:

```
$(document).ready(
        function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'Test/Service/hello',
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: {name: 'paco'},
                error: function () {
                    $('#etiqueta').html('An error has occurred');
                },
                success: function (data) {

                    console.debug(data);
                    $("#etiqueta").html('<p>' + data.d + '</p>');
                },
                type: 'POST'
            });
        }
);
```

Java:

```
@Path("/Service")
public class Service {

    public Service() {
    }

    /**
     * This is a sample web service operation
     *
     * @param txt
     * @return
     */
    @POST
    @Path("/hello")
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String hello(@WebParam(name = "name") String txt) {

        return "{\"d\": \"Hello " + txt + " !\"}";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
public String hello(@WebParam(name = "name") String txt) {

        return "Hello " + txt + " !";
    }
```

try to use:

```
public String hello(@WebParam(name = "name") String txt) {

        return "{\"d\" : \"Hello " + txt + " !\"}";
    }
```

If you returns some complex class, for example Product, it's converted to json, but  if you return String, lib can't convert it to {key=value} and think that you generated json manualy. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26115076/producing-and-consuming-custom-json-objects-in-spring-restful-services) to more info.

Comment: Still the same error but i see this on preview tab: {d = 'Hello name=paco !'}

Comment: Why "name=paco" if in javascript "name: 'testing'" ? You really sure that run that javascript as you show before?

Comment: Ooo, sorry. Of course, correct string is {\"d\": \"Hello " + txt + " !\"}. I fixed answer.

Comment: I just tryed another name. I'm sure i run that js, i just got it. If i change the dataType to text it works, even with the MediaType in java. And data is the string. Updated with more code.

Comment: I fixed code, correct string of course {\"d\": \"Hello " + txt + " !\"}, please try  this.

Comment: Now it works as you said. Another question, can i autogenerate the json when send an object?. Just like with a .Net Web Service. I don't care about using gson or something like that, i just want to autogenerate the json.

Comment: Yep, of course, you can autogenerate, just return, for example Map: public Map hello(...) { Map map = new HashMap(); map.put("d", "Hello"); return map; }

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot.