# Passing data from SpringMVC website to another SpringMVC website using json

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc

Today I have been given a new task and dont know how to go about it. I have two websites written in Spring MVC that does registration and payment processing.
On beginning the registration process on the first portal, when it comes to payment the user is thereby directed to the second portal to complete the payment and thereby returns the person back to the first website. 
The registration details entered by the user is required to be transferred from the first portal to the second portal in other to generate the required payment processing.
My question is, please what are the steps to channel my efforts towards using JSON to transfer data from one portal to another considering data security using Spring MVC. Please I need your ideas.

Comment: you can use rest methods and for the second portal say in your method that consumes "json" then you can send a full json entity without problems, same to return result from 2nd portal to first

Comment: What rest methods do u mean?

Comment: This is what would you need. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26115076/producing-and-consuming-custom-json-objects-in-spring-restful-services with rest services i mean you can communicate different logic depending on url if you need several operations, but nevermind