# Checking retrieved data format is in JSON or Invalid format using Spring Boot

Tags: json, validation, spring-boot

I am trying to identify the data format of retrieving data in a REST end point. I planning to only give response for request that having JSON data format when API is calling. From the retrieved header I am planning to identify that.

I am defining the end point is like following structure:

```
@PostMapping("/login/checkAuthorization")
  public PrivillegeResponse  checkAuthorizationAction(@RequestBody 
       PrivillegeModel privillegeObj ) 
        {
          //codes to be executed
           //giving JSON response
        }
```

Before giving its business logic implementation , I need to verify that the data retrieved is JSON data. What are the possibilities to achieve these functionalities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SpringBoot , you need to define the Class with @RestController .

For restricting it to Json , just define the consumes="application/json" attribute .

You can refer to ::

[Producing and consuming custom JSON Objects in Spring RESTful services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26115076/producing-and-consuming-custom-json-objects-in-spring-restful-services)

For a Generic Approach,check 
[Spring RequestMapping for controllers that produce and consume JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35123835/spring-requestmapping-for-controllers-that-produce-and-consume-json/35195033)

Comment: Thank you for your response and reply.

Comment: Glad it helped !